# Глупый вопрос — по какой причине нету margin:20px; со всех сторон?

Tags: html, css

```css
*{
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

div{
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
border:4px solid #000;
margin:20px 20px 30px;
margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

почему с права нету отступа ведь назначен 20px ?
я так всегда думал что 20px + block100% + 20px = scroll

Comment: сделайте ответом - я убрал 100% и margin = 20px со всех сторон

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное из-за width:100%. Ширина вашего div устанавливается в ширину родительского элемента.

Comment: а на самом деле сделать 20px + div 100% div + 20px реально сделать ?? именно 100%

Comment: Если не задавать width блочному элементу, он и так займет всю ширину родителя. Т.е. специально ничего не надо делать.

Comment: Если совсем принципиально, то как то так: width: calc(100% - 40px)

Comment: а тут два раза выбрать лучший ответ можно???